# stop compilation switching to clang

Tags: clang

No matter what I try, any compilation I attempt always calls clang. For example, in CMake, setting `CC=/usr/bin/gcc` has no effect and clang is still called. In terminal entering any compiler results in clang being called:

```
~/tinyos-main/tools$ nescc
clang: error: no input files
~/tinyos-main/tools$ gcc
clang: error: no input files
```

Can I stop this? Running on OS X Yosemite and using home-brew.

```
~$ /usr/bin/gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Are you shure GCC is installed? What's the output of `/usr/bin/gcc --verion` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, gcc is **not** installed as `/usr/bin/gcc`.  Clang is installed as `/usr/bin/gcc`, because Apple doesn't ship gcc anymore. If you want gcc, you need to install it (presumably by saying `brew install gcc`) and then setting `CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc`.